# Trying to pass Imageview onto viewpagerfragment

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, bundle

So I'm trying to create a viewpager of 26 different layouts based on the same layout file and I'm trying to pass the texts and images through a bundle. I got the text part down but I'm confused on how to put an Image in the bundle.

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {
//Resources mResources = getResources();
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alphabet, container, false);
    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.alphabet);
   // ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.letter);
    //Drawable drawable = mResources.getDrawable(R.drawable.aletter);
    //iv.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    tv.setText(getArguments().getString("msg"));

    return v;
}


public static ScreenSlidePageFragment newInstance(String text, Drawable drawable) {

    ScreenSlidePageFragment f = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("msg", text);
   // b.putInt();

    f.setArguments(b);

    return f;
}
```

}

```
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position) {
            case 0: return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1");
            case 1: return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 2");
            case 2: return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 3");
            case 3: return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 4");
            case 4: return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 5");
            case 5: return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 6");
            case 6: return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 7");
            case 7: return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 8");
            case 8: return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 9");
            case 9: return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 10");
            case 10: return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 11");
            case 11: return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 12");
            case 12: return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 13");
            case 13: return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 14");
            case 14: return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 15");
            case 15: return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 16");
            case 16: return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 17");
            case 17: return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 18");
            case 18: return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 19");
            case 19: return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 20");
            case 20: return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 21");
            case 21: return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 22");
            case 22: return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 23");
            case 23: return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 24");
            case 24: return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 25");
            case 25: return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 26");
            default: return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1");

        }
    }
```

Comment: oh boy that switch...

Comment: yeah, the switch can be improved with a map, but be careful of memory leaks

Comment: Does the way I have it cause the app to run slow or use more memory than necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have an ImageView declared in your alphabet layout.

```
... some layout container ...
<ImageView android:id="@+id/letter" android:width="wrap_content" android:height="wrap_content" />
... some other layouts...
```

Then in your onCreateView, you can find this ImageView and you can get the resource for that image from the bundle.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alphabet, container, false);
  TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.alphabet);
  ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.letter);
  iv.setImageResource(getArguments().getInt("letter")); // maybe check first if the argument is set :)
  tv.setText(getArguments().getString("msg"));

  return v;
}
```

in your newInstance method, you can set the correct resource as a fragment argument.

```
public static ScreenSlidePageFragment newInstance(String text, @DrawableRes int drawable) {
  ScreenSlidePageFragment f = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
  Bundle b = new Bundle();
  b.putString("msg", text);
  b.putInt("letter", drawable); // this is the image in your drawable folder that you can access with R.drawable.letter_a (if the file is called letter_a.png

  f.setArguments(b);

  return f;
}
```

Comment: So i plan to have an image, image and an imagebutton (will remove the text) so I can just do all three the same way right?

Comment: Yes, in general, you can pass all kinds of primitive and serializable/parcelable types in the bundle. But if you have more data to pass, maybe consider some kind of discriminator that you can pass and then do the work in the fragment. However, this is purely optional.

Comment: I'm gettting this error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.bignerdranch.android.learningisfun.ScreenSlidePagerActivity.getDrawable                                                               for this code                                                      case 0: return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1", getDrawable(R.drawable.aletter));

Comment: I'm sorry the comment is so messy. I'm terrible at posting and making it look organized.

Comment: Ignore the previous comments I got it

Answer (score 0):

Using `Parcelable` is more flexible when you want to add more fields.

First, create you own object e.g. `Screen.java` which contain fields *message* and *picture* (Drawable)

```
public class Screen implements Parcelable {

    public String message;   
    public Drawable picture;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Screen(String message, Drawable picture){
        this.message = message;
        this.picture = picture;
    }

    /**
     * constructor to rebuild object from the Parcel
     * @param source, a parcel data
     */
    public Screen(Parcel source) {
        this.message = source.readString();       
        this.picture = new BitmapDrawable(
                ( (Bitmap) source.readValue(Bitmap.class.getClassLoader()) )
        );
    }

     /**
     * describe the kind of special object
     */
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return hashCode();
    }

    /**
     * write this object in to a Parcel
     */
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(message);     
        dest.writeValue(((BitmapDrawable)picture).getBitmap());
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Screen> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Screen>() {
        public Screen createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Screen(source);
        }

        public Screen[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Screen[size];
        }
    };

 }
```

Next, you can start passing and receiving the `Parcelable` in your Fragment.

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alphabet, container, false);
    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.alphabet);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.letter);


    final Screen screen =  getArguments().getParcelable("screen");
    iv.setImageDrawable(screen.picture);
    tv.setText(screen.message);

    return v;
}


public static ScreenSlidePageFragment newInstance(String text, Drawable drawable) {

    ScreenSlidePageFragment f = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
    Screen screen = new Screen(text, drawable);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putParcelable("screen", screen);
    f.setArguments(b);

    return f;
}
```

Hope this will help you!